# Modx Revo 2.2.10 - page reloads on save resource

Tags: save, reload, modx-revolution

I've got a webseite with a second user called "editor". When I'm logged in as the "editor" and I edit a resource and hit "save", the page saves as it is meant to be, but the browser automatically reloads and opens the "new document" page. Quite annoying...

When I do the same with the admin-account (edit page, hit "save") everything happens as expected. The edits get changed and nothing more happens...

Any hints on this? Every help is much appreciated!

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the top right hand corner of the page there are 3 icons, 'Add another' 'continue editing' and 'close' I think you want to toggle that to 'continue editing' while logged in as the editor user.

Comment: ah...wow...never saw those buttons before...or didn't realize them! Thanks a lot!